# tbb alias works in zsh and not in bash, can anybody tell me why?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, support, bash

I have the following alias in 2 systems, the only difference between them is one uses bash/dash, while the other uses zsh, both systems running Debian testing.

The alias is :-

```
$ alias tor
alias tor='/home/shirish/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86-64/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser'
```

Now if I try to do the same in bash I get the following :-

```
$ tor
bash: /home/shirish/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86-64/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser: No such file or directory
```

remarkably, if I go to the desired directory and then start the service, it works :-

```
~/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Browser Tue Dec 08 13:32 $ ./start-tor-browser
```

any ideas what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Looks like there's a typo: `x86-64` vs `x86_64`. Hyphen vs underscore. Possibly just a transcription error in your question?

Comment: aaah, user error, thank you, that solved it. This is what happens when you are 10-12 hours in front of PC, thank you.